# Maven update component version in all components using it

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml, versions-maven-plugin

My project consists of numerous (~100) components, most of them use ~10 core components. When I update a version of a core component I would like to have up-to-date version of it in every component that is using it.

Trouble is that components depend on many other components - and I want only one of these dependencies updated at a time (the one that has just been updated).

I am using versions-maven-plugin and the "[update-properties](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html)" mojo - trouble is that it requires executing maven for each and every component in order to check if it needs update and doing the actual property update. I'm using Jenkins as a CI solution, tried that writing a custom pipeline and it sure is doable but it's still iterating over a whole project...

I was wondering if there maybe is a more efficient way to do this?

Would creating/maintaining dependency map be feasible here - do you know of any software that could be integrated into the pipeline to do that? (a little clarification here: all of my components are under the same maven groupid and the same project in gitlab).

Comment: This is not a Maven multi-module project, right?

Comment: @JFMeier Some of the child repos mentioned are multi-module, but only a few. In general it is one maven project per git repository.